# Removing a Rayburn Solid Fuel Cooker - Issues to consider

Tags: kitchens, chimney

I have a solid fuel Rayburn Regent cooker (essentially an Aga) with built in boiler in my kitchen, which I want to remove. It is no longer connected to the heating system, but appears to be connected to the chimney.

Are there any particular risks involved with dismantling this type of cooker to remove it? I'm thinking things such as asbestos linings or side effects of opening the chimney, rather than sharp edges or similar.

Comment: Wow my great grand mother had one. The vent pipe on hers was asbestos shielded back then we just used dust masks but you should have the material on the pipe checked so you and your house don't get contaminated. The wrap looked like gray cardboard that was the really bad stuff, also a cloth like substance that was asbestos filled on the 45 bends. Other than how heavy it was it was really hard for me and my dad to move and we are large guys. Patching the chimney  we used fire brick mortar to patch the hole. FYI there are folks that might purchase a old one in good shape.